# facebook send dialog prepopulated with text

Tags: facebook

I am developing an application where I want to be able to send messages to friends.

I want to display a list of friends and besides each friend there is a button which triggers the send dialog.

But I want the dialog to be prepopulated with the friends's name and a text like: I want to invite you to this event..

How can I do this?

PS: I am not intending to send messages to multiple users at one time, as this is not possible. For each message sent there will be necessary the user hiting the send button

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not possible, the Send button is designed for sharing URLs and doesn't allow the page owner to set the message which will be shared along with the content, or the intended recipients - it runs in an iframe so the browser security model will prevent you trying to do this manually.

If you want to have users send customised messages, check out the Feed dialog: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Comment: is there a way to send a message to a friend, other than the send dialog? The feed will post only to my wall

Comment: If you want the user to send a private message containing your link, use the Send dialog. If you want the user to share content of your choosing, use the Feed dialog. If you build your own interface you could have custom content shared to other walls, pages, groups, etc, but not to user inboxes

Comment: @Igy, could you help please here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66654709/facebook-sdk-send-method-in-reactjs