# Facebook sdk send method in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I added the facebook sdk according to [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog/#send-dialog):

```js
FB.ui({
  method: 'send',
  link: 'http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2015/04/15/travel/europe-favorite-streets.html',
});
```

When i type in message field:
[image] the link: `http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2015/04/15/travel/europe-favorite-streets.html` is overridden in the chat and appears just the `message`, but i want to keep both message and link that is sent in the chat. Why this happens and how to solve?

Comment: sounds like a but if message or link does not appear in the chat after send...maybe file a bug report on facebook?

Comment: @luschn, if i choose a friend and don't type something in the `message` filed then the `link` from `FB.ui` appears in the facebook chat, but if i choose a friend and after that i type a message in the `message` field, then in facebook chat appears just the message that typed, without the `link`. Why, do you think that this happens? Did you faced you the same issue?

Comment: @luschn, `maybe file a bug report on facebook`, what do you mean?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/